# Equivalence relation ≈L, for L ⊆ Σ*. Find u ≈L1 v and u !≈L2 v.

Tags: equivalence-relations, regular-language

Consider an alphabet Σ. This question concerns the equivalence relation ≈L, for L ⊆ Σ∗ .

(a) Give a language L1 such that, for any u, v ∈ Σ ∗ , we have u ≈L1 v.

(b) Give a language L2 such that, for any u, v ∈ Σ ∗ with u != v, |u| = |v|, we have u !≈L2 v

Sorry I couldn't copy the non-equal or non-equivalence side over from the text so I added the !.

I believe to answer this question I'm supposed to make a language then think of two strings, u and v, that both satisfy the language. For (a) I tried doing Σ = {a, b}, L1 = {w ∈ Σ∗: |w| is even}, u = [ε, aa, ab, ba, aaaa, ...], v = [ε, aa, bb, aabb, ...]. Now I'm not too sure what to do for (b) because u cannot equal v. Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: For (a) do you mean that for any $u,v\in\Sigma^*$, $u\approx_{L_1}v$? And by $u\approx_Lv$ do you mean that for all $w\in\Sigma^*$, $uw\in L$ iff $vw\in L$? If so, your example for (a) is correct.

Comment: Yeah for (a) you are right about your first question. As for u ≈L1 v, I mean that there are 2 strings u and v that are in the same equivalence class as L. E.g. u=ab and v=bb are both even, hence they are equivalent to the even length equivalence class.

Comment: You really haven’t answered my second question, since it makes little sense to talk about equivalence classes without saying what the equivalence relation is. When you say that two words $u$ and $v$ are equivalent with respect to $L$, do you mean that for each $w\in\Sigma^*$, either both of $uw$ and $vw$ are in $L$, or neither of them is in $L$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean both uw and vw are in L

Comment: (I’m going to assume that you really mean the standard notion, which is what I wrote, and not what you wrote in your last comment.) For (b) you can take any $\Sigma$ with at least $2$ elements and let $L_2$ be the set of palindromes in $\Sigma^*$.